# Interface 'SessionHandlerInterface' not found in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/CacheBasedSessionHandler.php on line 8

Tags: php, laravel, session, caching, handler

I cloned a repository and created a development environment with docker and nginx as a server. However, when running the composer install command I run into the following error:

[Error running composer install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJS97.png)

And in the browser:

[in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/429yo.png)

*I'm use ubuntu 20.04

Comment: `SessionHandlerInterface` is only available for PHP v5.4.0 and higher. What PHP version are you running?

Comment: I use version 7.4.3

Answer (score 0):

Install PHP session package

```
# pkg install php7.4-session
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup PHP-FPM for Apache2

```
sudo apt-get install php-fpm
restart php-fpm.service
```

Comment: I'm using nginx, not apache

Comment: @MatheusLima, You can also use PHP-FPM services for nginx

Comment: I tried to configure php-fpm to nginx, but to no avail

Comment: @MatheusLima Please refer https://www.journaldev.com/26097/php-fpm-nginx link might be helpful for you

Comment: I followed the steps, but the error persists :/

Comment: @MatheusLima re-install Nginx in your PC flow with  https://journaldev.com/26097/php-fpm-nginx link steps